# Requirejs loading plugins

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to load a plugin using requirejs but occasionally get an error, "$.fn is undefined" but if I reload the page the error disappears almost like now jquery is cached the problem is removed. I'm loading my libraries like this:

```
require(["jquery-1.4", "/script/jquery.autoSuggest.packed.js"], function($) {
   $(function() {
       //code
    });
});
```

Can you see if there is anything wrong with this implementation that would cause this error? Require js is being added to the page as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.co.uk/frameworks/requirejs/0.2.4/sharedmodules/require.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">  requireMap = {
     "jquery-1.4":"http://website.co.uk/sharedmodules/jquery-1.4"
}; 

    require({ baseUrl: 'http://website.co.uk/', paths: requireMap });      
</script>
```

This can't be changed as it's part of the framework I'm using.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

order plugin is removed. use shim loading as follows

```
requirejs.config({
   paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min',
        'bootstrap': '../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
        'select2': 'vendor/select2',
        'jshashtable': 'vendor/jshashtable-2.1',
        'jquery.numberformatter': 'vendor/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.min',
        'jq-datepicker': 'vendor/bootstrap-datepicker',
        'jq-datepicker.da': 'vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.da'
    }, 

    // Use shim for plugins that does not support AMD
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
        'select2': ['jquery'],
        'jq-datepicker': ['jquery'],
        'jshashtable': ['jquery'],
        'jquery.numberformatter': ['jquery', 'jshashtable']
    },

});
```

reference : http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Answer (score 8):

You will want to use the [order plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#order). By default RequireJS loads scripts as fast as possible, and they can load out of order. However, the order plugin will maintain the order of the script loads.

If you use the optimizer to optimizer your scripts, be sure to include both jQuery and the plugin in the optimized script.

Comment: um. does that still apply to jQuery 1.7?

Comment: @Stann yes, still applies for jQuery 1.7. While jQuery 1.7 registers as an AMD module, the jQuery plugin probably does not wrap its code in a define() wrapper, asking for 'jquery' as a dependency. So the problem is really with the jQuery plugin -- if it loads before jQuery has loaded there will be a problem, unless the plugin wraps itself in an AMD define() call.

Comment: For those that found this via, the order plugin isn't provided for RequireJS 2.0, so @jrburke's link above won't help.  You can still use the [1.0 API with the order plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#order), but a better solution is to use [2.0 with the shim configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

Comment: Down-voted because this answer is out-of-date now. As @KongaRaju has pointed out, the Order plugin has been removed and using SHIM is the preferred method. Hate to down-vote, but if an answer is no longer valid, then it shouldn't be highly scored anymore as people will follow the wrong methods.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to checkout https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/patterns

It has some good boilerplate jQuery plugin code that will work with RequireJS.

I think you may have to upgrade your jQuery to 1.7 before these patterns will work for you.

Comment: link that you provided seems to be broken, but this link it OK https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns/